# Definition of Bilinear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading the book 'Introduction to hilbert space and the theory of spectral multiplicity' and in chapter 1, section 2, it gives the definition of bilinear functional as

> A bilinear functional on a complex vector space $C$ is a complex valued function $\phi$ on the cartesian product of $C$ with itself such that if $\xi_y(x) = \eta_x(y) = \phi(x,y)$, then for every $x$ and $y$ in $C$, $\xi_y$ is a linear functional and $\eta_x$ is a conjugate linear functional.

I tried to search through the internet, but couldn't find the such a definition of Bilinear functionals. Could someone please help me understand it?

PS: I don't have a formal math background but I learnt a lot of math in my engineering curriculum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is more clear: To say that a function $\phi:C \times C \to \mathbb C$ is bilinear means that if $x, y \in C$ then the function $\phi(\cdot, y)$ is linear and the function $\phi(x, \cdot)$ is conjugate linear.

In the passage you quoted, the function $\phi(\cdot,y)$ is denoted $\xi_y$ and the function $\phi(x,\cdot)$ is denoted $\eta_x$.

Comment: why is $\phi(x,y)$ =  $\eta_x(y)$ = $\xi_y(x)$? What does that signify?

Comment: @AakashGupta This simply means that we can think of $\phi(x,y)$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ *or* as a family of functions of $y$, parameterised by $x$ *or* as a family of functions of $x$, parameterised by $y$. If you think of $\phi(x,y)$ as a surface then $\eta_x(y)$ and $\xi_y(x)$ are like cross- sections of that surface.